custom repositories in TypeORM
I wanted to use custom repositories in TypeORM, but I found that @EntityRepository(User) was deprecated. I ended up with this solution, which is ultimately working for me. However, I want to know if it is optimal or if it is redundant, inefficient, or something like that.
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { User } from '../entities/user.entity';
import { UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

export class UserRepository extends Repository<User> {
  
  @InjectRepository(User)
  userRepository: Repository<User>;

  async findByCodeOrEmail(userCredentials: string): Promise<User | undefined> {
    try {
      const user = await this.userRepository.findOne({
        where: [
          { code: userCredentials },
          { email: userCredentials }
        ]
      });
      return user;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error in UserRepository:', error);
      throw new UnauthorizedException('Error con credenciales');
    }
  }
}

I encountered deprecated functions for using custom repositories and found a solution that I am not sure is the best.

Yes, now the syntax is different. So now it use dataSource to get repository and extend it functionality. Official doc. https://typeorm.io/custom-repository.
Here's an example of how your entity should look.
import { User } from '../entities/user.entity';
import { UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { appDataSource } from 'src/database/app-data-source';

export const UserRepository = appDataSource.getRepository(User).extend({
  async findByCodeOrEmail(userCredentials: string): Promise<User | undefined> {
    try {
      const user = await this.userRepository.findOne({
        where: [{ code: userCredentials }, { email: userCredentials }],
      });
      return user;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error in UserRepository:', error);
      throw new UnauthorizedException('Error con credenciales');
    }
  },
});

You should have a dataSource (in provided example appDataSource is a dataSource for default DB, in case you have connections to different DB in your app). Here's official doc of dataSource https://typeorm.io/data-source-api.
Also note that after refactoring of custom repository (for example UserRepository) - you need to update all places where it used:

Remove from modules files
Remove it from constuctor in services (and etc) and use just as imported function
If you used it as as type - you also should update it, because now it's function, not class

